# C program giving extremely wrong answer

Tags: c

Program takes an integer input `num` from the keyboard and computes the sum of square of `i` for all `I` from `1` to `num` (inclusive).

```c
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int num;
    int total;
    printf("Please enter a number:");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    for (double i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
        total += (i*i);
        printf("%d", total);
    }
}
```

The code above compiles correctly, but when inputting `5` it prints `15143055`. Why is it doing this?

Comment: `total` does not appear to be initialized.

Comment: like you want me to put int total=0;? because it doesn't change anything

Comment: Um, `iostream` is not C. Did you mean `#include <stdio.h>`?

Comment: Yes, that would initialize `total` to zero.

Comment: vlab automatically inputs that

Comment: output remains 15143055

Comment: odd choice using a `double` for your loop control variable

Comment: yeah i normally dont, was toying with it to see if it would change output

Comment: changing loop variable to int still results in an output of 15143055

Comment: You're printing each subtotal. So it prints 1, then 1+4 = 5, then 5+9 = 14, etc.

Comment: You print in every iteration. It's intermediate sums concatenated together due to lack of whitespace. Put the `printf()` out of loop

Comment: Or add a newline or space after each printf.

Comment: yeah that did it. feel like an idiot. thanks everyone

Comment: also no need to `#include <math.h>`

Comment: @Schelts could you please write an answer to mark this question as answered?

Comment: Rule of thumb: Unless you're doing something special, always end your `printf` format strings with `\n`.  Do write `"%d\n"`.  Don't write `"%d"`, or `"\n%d"`.

Answer (score 0):

`#include <iostream>` is c++.  `#include <math>` is not used.  `total` is uninitialized.  Comparing floating point values may not behave the way you want, so using a (unsigned) integer type instead as a loop counter. Loop values by convention start at 0 instead of 1 in c (you could increment `i` fist thing in the loop to avoid the double `(i+1)` but this will be optimized out anyways).  Also, your loop not run for a negative value so just require unsigned values.  As you sum integers the result ought to be an integer, but double would give you a larger range so I left it as such.  Missing `return`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    unsigned num;
    printf("Please enter a number: ");
    scanf("%u", &num);

    double total = 0.0;
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        total += (i+1)*(i+1);
    }
    printf("%lf\n", total);

    return 0;
}
```

and the resulting output:

```
Please enter a number: 3
14.000000
```